# SQL Query returning type unit while using F#

Tags: entity-framework, f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I am trying F# for the first time. I know I need to be able to access the database to do any significant work. We have been using Entity framework for some time. So I was able to use an existing Model file. The file was made using EF5 and I also installed EF5 on the F# project (using nuget). Here is the code I've written.

```ml
open System.Data
open System.Data.Entity
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

let connectionString = "metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string='data source=&quot;(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dev)))&quot;;password=888888888888888;user id=444444444444444'"

type internal edmx = EdmxFile<"Model.edmx", ResolutionFolder = @"C:\Users\ahernandez\Documents\Source Control\Web\Applications\NACS_API\NAWS_API\Models">

let internal context = new edmx.Model.Entities(connectionString)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main = 
    query { for ua_event in context.MV_COURSE_SCHEDULE do
            select ua_event } 
    |> Seq.iter (fun ua_event -> printfn "%s" ua_event.EVE_EVENT_CODE)
```

I just get one error:

```
Error   1   Type mismatch. Expecting a
    System.Linq.IQueryable<string> -> string [] -> int    
but given a
    System.Linq.IQueryable<string> -> unit    
The type 'string [] -> int' does not match the type 'unit'  c:\users\ahernandez\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestFsOracle1\Program.fs  26  8   TestFsOracle1
```

The error gives me the impression that the query is failing for some reason. I would think if there was an Entity Framework error, I would see that error as well. Any ideas?

Comment: You make iteration part of `main`. I think you want to do `main |> Seq.iter ...` after the `let` statement.

Comment: @GertArnold you pointed me in the right direction. Being a console app, 'main' has to have an argument and return a number. I am on the fence about deleting the question. If you want the credit you can respond to it.